# How to match an object consisting of other objects with Orika

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto, orika

I have three classes of entity(order,customer,sallers) and three classes of Dto. Me need to use Orika for mapping objects from entity classes to Dto. One of this(order) consist of  data and links to another Dto objects. How i can map order entity to orderDto with *orika* uses mapperFactory or different sight mapper in orika. At the moment i have a two mapperFactory for transfer Sellers and Customers to Dto maybe can i use them?

### Classes of entity

(hide not important information)

**Orders**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Orders")
@Data
public class Orders {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "seller_id", nullable = false)
    private Sellers seller;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customers customer;  
}
```

**Customers**

```
    public class Customers {
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order_id")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties
        private Set<Orders> orders; 
}
```

**Sellers**

```
public class Sellers{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order_id")
    private Set<Orders> orders;}
```

### DTO

**OrdersDto**

```
public class OrdersDto
    {
        private SellersDto seller;
        private CustomersDto customer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i used this solution:

You need to change your DTO class. Just change inheritance links from dto to Entity.

```
 public class OrdersDto
    {
        private  Sellers seller // old: SellersDto seller;
        private  Customers customer;  // old: CustomersDto customer;
    }
```

Names of fields in your entity and dto class should be equals by name. For correct links on database use @JoinColumn and @Column. And when you use:

```
 mapperFactory.classMap(OrdersDto.class, Orders.class).byDefault().register();
```

Your inner classes (for example, Sellers and Buyers for me) are automatically rendered by fields because their fields are also rendered "by default".